# Mono(Touch): System.Xml.Schema.Extensions

Tags: mono, xsd, linq-to-xml, xamarin.ios

I tried validating an XML file via the [`XDocument.Validate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.validate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method defined in `System.Xml.Schema.Extensions`. However the compiler says that `XDocument` “does not contain a definition for ‘Validate’ and no extension method ‘Validate’ of type ‘System.Xml.Linq.XDocument’ could be found”.

Is the `System.Xml.Schema.Extensions` class really missing from MonoTouch? And if so, is there any other way to validate an XML read into a XDocument?

#### edit:

The class in question seems to be missing from Mono as well, according to their [documentation](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N%3aSystem.Xml.Schema). Is there any replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoTouch is based on the Silverlight profile.  Neither Silverlight nor WinPhone7 include System.Xml.Schema.Extensions.

Fortunately, Mono is open source, so you can take the code you need and add it to your project:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Xml.Linq/System.Xml.Schema/Extensions.cs

Comment: That‘s perfect, thank you very much! I guess the Mono documentation is then just horribly outdated (after checking now, the whole `System.Xml.Linq` namespace is missing there).

Answer (score 0):

Extensions appears to be new in 3.5 - MonoTouch is core 2.0, with bits of later versions (ie, LINQ) included.

Comment: MonoTouch‘ whole `System.Xml` namespace is as of .NET 3.5 as described in their [assemblies list](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Assemblies), and that class appears to be the only missing class in that namespace.